# How to programmatically get Google product reports (pulled via API) into AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-api, double-click

I am looking to pull a monthly performance report of a campaign running in Double click bid manager, I'm pulling this report via the `DoubleClick Bid Manager API(https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/v1/queries/createquery).

I just plug the JASON syntax with the account and various fields, when I click on execute I'm able to download the reports from the reports tab of bid manager, then I'm uploading it to S3 manually so that I can later dump it into Redshift.

I was wondering if there was a way I can do this programmatically, instead of uploading the report manually every time.

If there is a question already on this, please point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the Bid Manager client library to fetch the data you're interested in? https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/doubleclickbidmanager/v1

Comment: Is the Redshift tag really relevant to this question? i.e are you wanting advice on how to load this data into Redshift, or just how to automate the extraction of data from the API?